# Build rpm for packages

Tags: linux, unix, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

Can any one tell me how to create an rpm which would install another rpm,how to find the spec file for this.Or please indicate the tutorial for building such a spec file

Answer (score 3):

You cannot. Specify the package you want installed as well in `Requires:` and let the depsolver handle it.

Comment: Yes this is the way I'd do it.